# Remove from URL haproxy

Tags: regex, haproxy, pfsense

I have an haproxy server and I need it to rewrite the URL.

For example, I have a url that is like this:

```
http://myserver.com/UserName/signalr/.....
```

and I need to remove the UserName, so when haproxy forwards to the server the url becomes:

```
http://myserver.com/signalr/.....
```

if I know the UserName then this works:

```
reqrep ^([^\ ]*\ /)UserName[/]?(.*)     \1\2
```

My problem is that the UserName is not a static, but always in the same place in the URL, directly after the domain.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Does `reqrep (myserver\.com[/])([^s]|s[^i]|si[^g]|sig[^n]|sign[^a]|signa[^l]|signal[^r])[^/]*[/]?(.*)     \1\3` work?

Comment: It does. Thank you very much!

Comment: I was too quick on my feet, it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find a solution to this if anyone is interested

```
reqrep ^([^)((?:[^\/]*\/){1}[^\/]*\/(.*)     \1\2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the regex `http:\/\/myserver.com\/(\w+)` to determine the username directly after the domain.  The first captured group is the username.